# python pandas - Check if partial string in column exists in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take a sample dataset:

`df = pd.DataFrame([['Mexico', 'Chile'], ['Nicaragua', 'Nica'], ['Colombia', 'Mex']], columns = ["col1", "col2"])`

The dataframe looks like this:

I have two columns. I want to check to see if the values in column two exist in column one. This includes checking for partial strings.

The desired output is:

[image]

I am able to compare the whole value of each row in column two, but this does not account for partial strings:

`df['compare'] = np.where(df['col2'].isin(df['col1']), 'yes', 'no')`

I am also able to check if a single value exists within a column, which checks for partial strings but does not include every row in the 'col2' column.

`df['compare'] = df['col1'].str.contains('Mex')`

How can I do both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an expensive operation. You can try:

```
df['col2'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if df['col1'].str.contains(x).any() else 'No')
```

Output:

```
0     No
1    Yes
2    Yes
Name: col2, dtype: object
```